# Dumb RichTextBox question

Tags: regex, tags, richtextbox

I need to get a list of tags in a text, make their contents bold, and remove them. Can't figure out how to make it.

E.g. with the following input:

foo [b]bar[/b]

The result should be:

foo **bar**

I use the following code to extract the tags:

```
 Dim matches = Regex.Matches(OriginalRich.Text, String.Format("(\[{0}\])(.*?)(\[/{0}\])", tag), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is the regex working? Do you need help with the RTB?

Comment: I'm having trouble highlighting the text and removing the tags at the same time. The result is incorrect (probably text shift is the cause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing it in two steps: apply the formatting to the whole match including the tags, then make another pass to remove the tags.  But if you're doing all this in the same control, I'd say *that's* your real problem.

I would use a plain TextBox for the input, with a non-editable RichTextBox to preview the result.  Basically, the same approach that's used here at StackOverflow (but with a different toolset).